# How to return binary data from custom wordpress rest api endpoint

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am writing a custom endpoint for a REST api in wordpress, following the guide here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

I am able to write a endpoint that returns json data. But how can I write an endpoint that returns binary data (pdf, png, and similar)?

My restpoint function returns a `WP_REST_Response` (or `WP_Error` in case of error).
But I do not see what I should return if I want to responde with binary data.

Comment: Are you looking to return a file for download, or perhaps just an image that can be rendered on screen?

Comment: Actually both: I generate pdfs and pngs on the server and want to provide them for download for the users. In addition I want very specific access rights to the resoueces, which I want to check for in the rest endpoints callback function.

Comment: Ive got some code for this from something Ive already done, give me a few moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at something called DOMPDF. In short, it streams any HTML DOM straight to the browser.
We use it to generate live copies of invoices straight from the woo admin, generate brochures based on $wp_query results etc. Anything that can be rendered by a browser can be streamed via DOMPDF.

Comment: @Nathan if the solution of DOMPDF is of any use, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to use DOMPDF to stream generic binary data (not necessarily in PDF format)? Also a link to DOMPDF would help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but I feel the accepted answer does not really answer the question, and Google found this question when I searched for the same solution, so here is how I eventually solved the same problem (i.e. avoiding to use `WP_REST_Response` and killing the PHP script before WP tried to send anything else other than my binary data).

```
function download(WP_REST_Request $request) {
  $dir = $request->get_param("dir");

  // The following is for security, but my implementation is out 
  // of scope for this answer. You should either skip this line if 
  // you trust your client, or implement it the way you need it.
  $dir = sanitize_path($dir);

  $file = $request->get_param("file");

  // See above...
  $file = sanitize_path($file);

  $sandbox = "/some/path/with/shared/files";
  
  // full path to the file
  $path = $sandbox.$dir.$file;

  $name = basename($path);

  // get the file mime type 
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $path);

  // tell the browser what it's about to receive
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name;");
  header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache private");

  // stream the file without loading it into RAM completely
  $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
  fpassthru($fp);

  // kill WP
  exit;
}
```